# I am all possible worlds, what am I?

Tags: riddle

I am the art of giving the same name to different things.
I am the supreme judge; from its decisions there is no appeal.
I am like love; a simple idea, but it can get complicated.
I am a great motivator for all humans.
I uses easy words for hard ideas.
I am an independent world created out of pure intelligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer could be

> Mathematics.

I am the art of giving the same name to different things.

> Or at least, so says [Henri Poincaré](http://izquotes.com/quote/146926).

I am the supreme judge; from its decisions there is no appeal.

> Mathematical truths can't be refuted.

I am like love; a simple idea, but it can get complicated.

> "Complicated" is an understatement.

I am a great motivator for all humans.

> Check.

I uses easy words for hard ideas.

> Check.

I am an independent world created out of pure intelligence.

> Makes sense.

Comment: 'Mathematical truths can't be refuted'? Surely any truth can be refuted. We have placed certainty in math, but that doesn't make it objective, merely reliably useful from our perspective. Truly a sad state of affairs, when people still assume human constructs are irrefutable, despite the obvious lack of rationale behind that belief.

Comment: @CallumBradbury I don't quite follow. AFAIK all mathematical truths are logical tautologies, and therefore irrefutable. Can you give an example?Maybe I'm misunderstanding your viewpoint?

Comment: I guess I'd ask what makes logical tautologies irrefutable? If the answer is 'that's what logical tautologies are defined as', then I don't believe any truly exist. A simple example would be 1+1=2, that is only true in certain scenarios, not an objective truth by any measure. As far as I'm aware, math tends to be reliant upon certain assumptions, the ultimate one being 'this is true in all scenarios. I guess from a human perspective they could be considered irrefutable, but I think it'd require a certain level of egotism about humanity to believe that makes them the supreme judge of anything.

Comment: @CallumBradbury Ahh, so your point is that logic itself may not be irrefutable. Of course, we can't really argue about that (because arguing means assuming a priori the validity of logic) and this is not the best place to discuss that, but I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: logic isn't really irrefutable, it's inherently bound by the information available to the person making their logical deductions. Of course, that being said, that observation is limited by the information available to me when making that deduction, so as you said, yeah, the argument itself somewhat renders the argument moot. Just thought I'd mention it as people stating things as irrefutable is a pet peeve of mine - carry on! :)